# How do I remove words from outputted string in PHP?

Tags: php, preg-replace

I'm new to PHP and trying to customize the following PHP line on my Joomla site:

```
<? if ($event->venue_id) : ?><?=@service('com://site/component.model.venues')->id($event->component_venue_id)->getItem()->title?><? endif ?>
```

The line outputs the address, but I want to shorten the outputted address by removing the city and country. Is this possible some how in PHP?

I have been trying to do it with 'preg_replace' but not having much success. All the addresses are UK address so I tried:

```
<? if ($event->venue_id) : ?><?=@service('com://site/component.model.venues')->id($event->component_venue_id)->getItem(preg_replace('UK','',($event->venue_id))->title?><? endif ?>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why do you output something if it is not mention to be output?

Comment: Show the format of the address ouptut or give an example. Also, show the preg_replace attempt you tried that didn't work; it may be almost right but have a small bug.

Comment: What is the exact string that is printed?

Comment: The adddress comes out like: "11 Water Square, London, Greater London A12 34Z, UK"

Comment: @Sarah, please edit your question to include that example. Also include what you would like it to look like (remember, edit the question, don't just post more comments). A few more examples would also be helpful so we can establish the pattern you are looking for; it's not clear from one example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to remove the `, UK` part, you don't need [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php), you can just do a regular [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

Change this:

```
@service('com://site/component.model.venues')->id($event->component_venue_id)->getItem()->title
```

To this:

```
str_replace(', UK', '', @service('com://site/component.model.venues')->id($event->component_venue_id)->getItem()->title)
```

This will replace `, UK` with an empty string. So it will turn an address like this:

```
11 Water Square, London, Greater London A12 34Z, UK
```

Into this:

```
11 Water Square, London, Greater London A12 34Z
```

If you also want to remove, for example, the string `London,`, you can just add another str_replace:

```
str_replace('London, ', '', str_replace(', UK', '', @service('com://site/component.model.venues')->id($event->component_venue_id)->getItem()->title))
```

This would result in that address becoming:

```
11 Water Square, Greater London A12 34Z
```